How to wrap generic functions callbacks with concrete types in typescript
What should I replace the ??? with? none of the attempts above it work.
declare function generic1<T>(t: T): T;
declare function generic2<T>(t: T): { a: T };
declare function generic3<T>(t: T): { b: T[] };
// etc...


// function string_wrapper<F extends <T>(t: T) => any>(f: F): ReturnType<typeof f<string>> {
// function string_wrapper<F extends (t: string) => any>(f: F): ReturnType<F> {
// function string_wrapper<R, F extends (t: string) => R>(f: F): R {
function string_wrapper<F extends ???>(f: F): ??? {
    return f('hi'); // should be F<string>
}

const r1 = string_wrapper(generic1); // should be: string
const r2 = string_wrapper(generic2); // should be: { a: string }
const r3 = string_wrapper(generic3); // should be: { b: string[] }

Playground link

This is not possible as written, TS doesn't have direct support for higher kinded types as requested in ms/TS#1213, nor does it quite have the sort of type-level generic function instantiation expression types you want. I don't understand why you need this behavior anyway, since the example is certainly amenable to just having the function generic in the return type, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, please [edit] to demonstrate.

Not possible. Got it. Thanks! The reason I would need this, is to get the return type without actually invoking a "wrapper", but from another type that would extract the return type.

Can you show a [mre] of that? Maybe there's some kind of alternative approach? Hard to say without seeing it, though

turning what you explained into a type, it would be something like this, but it's not possible because of the higher kinded types thingy.
It's workaroundable with values but not with types since you can't declare the type parameter to be just R, like with the function. Shame.

This is a missing feature of TypeScript. You currently cannot use conditional type inference to instantiate type arguments in generic functions the way you can when you call a generic function or when you assign a generic function to a specific function type.  See microsoft/TypeScript#22617. What instead happens is that generic type parameters are first instantiated with their constraints before inference. In practice that means you'll get a lot of unknown when you try to do this.

Thanks for pointing out the open issue more closely related to this.
Some of these issues are so old that they're difficult to find. It gives little hope that they will get to be implemented sometime.
It also makes me wonder, how come they aren't closed with "Design Limitation" like other similar issues.
